# Doesn't support framework version: between 21 and 31 for Android app

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, google-play-console

Today I noticed on PlayStore console that some of Google Devices like Google Pixel 4 XL, Pixel 4a etc are not supported for my app. (My app is Cordova based)

The message for not supporting the device is **Doesn't support framework version: between 21 and 31**

I am not sure what this message mean. I am able to run my app app on same device emulator (Pixel 4 XL Android 12).

Here is the image for better understanding.

[image]

#### Here is my minSDK, targetSDK, maxSDK etc

```
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 31
    maxSdkVersion 31
    compileSdkVersion 31
```

#### Manifest permission and features

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.location" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: We'd need to see your app's manifest with the permissions and uses-feature declarations to find the issue.

Comment: Added the permission and uses-feature in the question @Pierre

Answer (score 1):

## maxSDKVersion was the issue.

My `build.gradle` has the maxSDKVersion = 31. Because of that PlayStore was not pushing my app to users with Android 12 (SDK version 32). So I just removed the `maxSdkVersion 31` from `build.gradle` and it worked.

### What was the confusion?

I did not realize that Android 12 has two SDK version.

- 31 (Android 12)
- 32 (Android 12L)

Also in my opinion the error message on PlayStore Device Catalog was vague.

#### Google Play Support Team:

I contacted Google [Play Store support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?_ga=2.124200258.916845789.1648571479-643640210.1631109989&_gac=1.24841928.1648823965.CjwKCAjwxZqSBhAHEiwASr9n9DahhJr6pbjQaEg6jQo_IOgORNzdrQSjNB0Mtlbks3XMKBjtF6zYShoC1nMQAvD_BwE#topic=3450769) team as well. They were able to locate the issue. They took 48 hours to respond (They usually take 24-72 hours). So it is another a good option for Android developers to reach out to Google Play Support team for PlayStore issues.

### How PlayStore shows your app to users?

AFAIK: Google PlayStore filters application based on AndroidManifest.xml and `build.gradle`

So if your app is not compatible or visible to some devices. Then you should start looking into your AndroidManifest and `build.gradle` file.

For example if you defined android.hardware.camera.front as  then will filter out your application for devices that do not have **front camera**.